# Python How to find and print minimum and maximum value in a list?

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have a code that prompts user to input a set of numbers and put them in a list. It also calculates the total of the numbers and the average... but I don't know how to find the biggest and smallest number in the list. How do I print them out **without using min() and max() functions**?

here's the code:

```
L = []
total = 0
average = 0
q="quit"
while True:
    num_input = input("Enter the number: ")
    if num_input == q:
        break
    else:
            L.append(num_input)
for j in L:
    total += j
    average = total / len(L)
print(total)
print(average)
```

Comment: Keep two variables, one for min, one for max, and compare them to j in your for loop. Save the smallest/biggest appropriately.

Comment: You can have 2 variable- min,max to keep track of the values. (If you don't want to use min(),max() functions   `minimum=L[0]
maximum=L[0]    for i in L:
    if i < minimum:

        minimum=i
    else:
        if i > maximum:
                  maximum=i`

Comment: Thanks! it worked :D